# zlib exception in _tr_tally_dist

Tags: c, exception, zlib

I am getting the following error from zlib deflate when using a chunk size of 262144.

*Access violation writing location 0x005AF000.*

The error occurs in _tr_tally_dist

The value of dist is 26885, last_lit = 35312.

Any ideas?

```
void _tr_tally_dist (s, distance, length, flush)
deflate_state *s;
unsigned int distance;
unsigned int length;
int flush;
{ 
    unsigned char  len = length;
    unsigned short dist = distance;
    flush = (s->last_lit >= s->lit_bufsize - 1);
    **s->d_buf[s->last_lit] = dist;**
    s->l_buf[s->last_lit++] = len;
    dist--;
    s->dyn_ltree[_length_code[len] + LITERALS + 1].Freq++;
    s->dyn_dtree[d_code (dist)].Freq++;

}
```

Comment: The crash is probably not in the zlib code, but in your. When the crash happens, you should look at the function call stack to see where in your code it happens. Please post that function, and maybe the call stack too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It is in the zlib code. The value of flush is passed by value and not by reference, therefore it never gets updated.

I changed the code to pass bflush by address and it worked.

Comment: No, it's not in the zlib code since that isn't the zlib code.

Comment: Correct. I changed a macro to C code and introduced the bug myself. The zlib code does not have a bug in it. The zlib code runs very fast under Windows 8 and IBM's z/OS mainframe. It is a great library for anyone considering compression IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the zlib code.  In [zlib, `_tr_tally_dist` is a macro](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/deflate.h), not a function.